# Sum of cells depending on neighbor value

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table like this

```
  | A | B | C
1 | 1 | 2 | 3
2 | a | a | b
3 | 4 | 5 | 6
4 | b | a | a
```

and I want to write a formula to sum each number in the table with 'a' letter under it. So in this case result is

```
1 + 2 + 5 + 6 = 14.
```

I try to use FILTER

```
SUM(FILTER(A1:C4, A2:C5 = "a"))
```

but get

```
error: Range must be 1xN or Nx1
```

Is it possible or I have to organize my data another way?

Answer (score 2):

Different data layout may be a better solution, but is not essential if you deal with one column at a time, say with:

```
=sum(filter(A1:A3,A2:A4="a"))
```

copied across and then the results summed.

Shorter, possibly more conventional (and IMO more elegant since just a single formula):

```
=sumif(A2:C4,"a",A1:C3)
```